# Access Db connection parameter from AWS Secrets from lambda using dotnet core

Tags: amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-lambda, aws-serverless, aws-secrets-manager

I am trying to develop a AWS Serverless API project using API gateway and lambda functions.
I am using SAM model provided by AWS and Visual studio's AWS Serverless project template which includes cloudformation template too.

I do not want to store DB information in configuration file due to security reasons,
I would like to know how can I use AWS Secrets Manager to get DB connection information in lambda function at run-time.

A code sample would be a great help as I could only find python examples using Boto3, .net core samples or explanation for serverless API and lmbda is not that much available on internet I guess.
Any help or clue would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[Approach 1]**

You may use [dynamic referencing](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/dynamic-references.html) in Cloudformation as follows:

- Create DB credentials in the Secret Manager.
- (Optional) Pass these credentials to the DB while creating it from Cloudformation.
- Pass these credentials to the Lambda Function's [environment variables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-lambda-function-environment.html) in Cloudformation.
- In the Lambda code simple read the referenced environment variables:

```
Console.WriteLine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DB_USERNAME"));
```

Example of dynamic referencing with DB:

```
{
    "MyRDSInstance": {
        "Type": "AWS::RDS::DBInstance",
        "Properties": {
            "DBName": "MyRDSInstance",
            "AllocatedStorage": "20",
            "DBInstanceClass": "db.t2.micro",
            "Engine": "mysql",
            "MasterUsername": "{{resolve:secretsmanager:MyRDSSecret:SecretString:username}}",
            "MasterUserPassword": "{{resolve:secretsmanager:MyRDSSecret:SecretString:password}}"
        }
    }
}
```

This approach is simple yet will need redeploys on credentials updates.

**[Approach 2]**

Alternatively, you may pass the Secret Manager variable names in the environment variables and then use those names to retrieve the values.

Add the nuget package for [SecretsManager](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AWSSDK.SecretsManager/). Write class for querying:

```
public class SecretManager : ISecretManager
{
  public string Get(string secretName)
  {
    var config = new AmazonSecretsManagerConfig {RegionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.EUWest1};
    var client = new AmazonSecretsManagerClient(config);

    var request = new GetSecretValueRequest
    {
      SecretId = secretName
    };

    GetSecretValueResponse response = null;
    try
    {
      response = Task.Run(async () => await client.GetSecretValueAsync(request)).Result;
    }
    catch (ResourceNotFoundException)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("The requested secret " + secretName + " was not found");
    }
    catch (InvalidRequestException e)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("The request was invalid due to: " + e.Message);
    }
    catch (InvalidParameterException e)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("The request had invalid params: " + e.Message);
    }

    return response?.SecretString;
  }
}
```

Use the class as follows:

```
var secretManager = new SecretManager();
var mongoDb = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MongoConnectionString>(secretManager.Get(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SECRET_NAME")));
var database = new MongoClient(mongoDb.ConnectionString);
```

Please refer to [this article](https://medium.com/@jonvines/using-aws-secrets-manager-with-dotnet-core-a44b54bba8d4) for more details.